# Windows 11 how to ungroup network, volume and battery corner icons on taskbar tray

Tags: battery, taskbar, icons, windows-11, notification-area

This is very annoying to me.

Windows 11 groups the network, volume and battery corner icons on taskbar tray. Like show on the following picture:

[image]

It also groups the interfaces of the respective popup dialogs, which annoys me even more.

For getting anything done, for example to connect to another wireless network, the user has to pass in more one hierarchy level.

Is there any way to get it more like the Windows 10 user interface? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher

ExplorerPatcher allows bringing back the window 10 taskbar, among other productivity/customization features.

You might want to take a look.